# Highlighting an element with allowed interaction

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to create my own product tour handling (after trying some like `intro.js`).

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/j6naexw8/13/) is a JSFiddle that I've just created.

What I have is a `div` with CSS:

```
.highlight {
  position: fixed;
  top: 14px;
  left: 16px;
  width: 54px;
  height: 40px;
  z-index: 1000;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.highlight__overlay {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 12;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: all .5s ease;
  border: 2000px solid rgba(0 ,0 ,0 ,0.85);
  margin: -1000px;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  transform: translate3d(-1000px, -1000px, 0);
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

As you can see, the button is highlighted, and clickable, but other two button can also be clicked.

How can I make only the element in the highlighted area clickable?

Also - are there any product tour/tutorial JS libraries that I should be aware of? Those, that will basically have the functionality that I need.

Comment: take a look a **EnjoyHint**, maybe it is what you are looking for: https://xbsoftware.com/products/enjoyhint/

Comment: And about the button, with your current structure, I would add a `disabled` to all `buttons`,  then remove the disabled just for the button that should be clicked in the current "tour step", using JS

Comment: Thanks a lot. EnjoyHint looks really great and I think I will fork it and modify a bit to match my needs. I also thought about disabling buttons etc, but this is not a universal solution

Comment: I'd rather do something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/j6naexw8/68/).

Comment: @VXp Thanks :) That's the path I went this morning!

Answer (score 1):

I have updated your jsfiddle [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/j6naexw8/53/)

I added `pointer-events: none` to the `button` section of your css and gave button One a class of `enabledButton`.

Then I added `pointer-events: auto` to the `.enabledButton` section of your css

With a single line of jquery you can remove the `enabledButton` class from all buttons:
`$("button").removeClass("enabledButton");`

You then add the `enabledButton` class only to the button you highlight.

Now, the button with the class of `enabledButton` will be clickable while all others are not. This way you explicitly enable the button you want the user to click while all other buttons are disabled by default.

Answer (score 0):

You can use css to do something like

```
. disabled{
       pointer-events : none;
    }
```

And add this class to the other non-highlighted buttons.

Another solution that requires some Javascript, is to add a default Html `disabled` attribute to your buttons, and remove it only for the highlighted button using `innerHTML` of something similar.